# JBOSS Guvnor / Drool - drools compiler error

Tags: jboss, drools, guvnor

I am trying to use Guvnor UI to create drools rules, but getting the following exception. Using Java 7. Error while creating the test scenarios and verification for the rules.

Using JBoss 7.1.1-Final

Drools libraries 6.4.0.Final

```
14:20:20,878 ERROR [org.drools.guvnor.server.ServiceImplementation] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) Unable to build asset.: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:283) [drools-compiler-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:268) [drools-compiler-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:181) [drools-compiler-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:143) [drools-compiler-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.BRMSPackageBuilder.getInstance(BRMSPackageBuilder.java:98) [classes:]
at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.ContentPackageAssembler.createBuilder(ContentPackageAssembler.java:160) [classes:]
at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.ContentPackageAssembler.<init>(ContentPackageAssembler.java:149) [classes:]
at org.drools.guvnor.server.ServiceImplementation.buildAsset(ServiceImplementation.java:1813) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:31) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.security.SecurityInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:157) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:166) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:102) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.drools.guvnor.server.ServiceImplementation_$$_javassist_4.buildAsset(ServiceImplementation_$$_javassist_4.java) [classes:]
at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryServiceServlet.buildAsset(RepositoryServiceServlet.java:251) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562) [gwt-servlet-2.0.4.jar:]
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188) [gwt-servlet-2.0.4.jar:]
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224) [gwt-servlet-2.0.4.jar:]
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [gwt-servlet-2.0.4.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ContextFilter$1.process(ContextFilter.java:42) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.ContextualHttpServletRequest.run(ContextualHttpServletRequest.java:53) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:37) [org.jboss.seam-jboss-seam-2.1.0.GA.jar:2.1.0.GA]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: value '1.7' is not a valid language level
at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.getDefaultLanguageLevel(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:162) [drools-compiler-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.init(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:57) [drools-compiler-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:279) [drools-compiler-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
... 55 more
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not using 6.4.0.Final. Java 1.7 is supported by [JavaDialectConfiguration in Drools 6.4.Final](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/6.4.x/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/rule/builder/dialect/java/JavaDialectConfiguration.java). 
The stacktrace doesn't show any KIE nor Uberfire classes, what makes me think you are still using Drools 5.x. Could you please double-check?

Comment: For my own Java code compilation i am definitely using 6.4.0-FINAL, but for UI i am using drools-5.1.1-guvnor.war, i don't know if that is using some lower version of Drools. Is it a possibility

Comment: I don't understand. What are you compiling? 
If you are deploying an unmodified version of guvnor.war from Drools 5.1.1, then the drools version it will internally use is 5.1.1. If you have manually updated the drools jars inside that war to 6.4.0, then good luck with that. If you want to use Drools 6.4, why aren't you using the Kie-Workbench (the replacement of Guvnor in 6.x) instead?